# match values between 2 dictionaries & append the matching value to the new dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to generate a table to compare between gold values & predicted values. The gold & predicted values are represented in 2 separate list of dictionaries which have different values & sizes.

***What I would like to do is:*** If the `id` value of a dictionary in the `gold` list exists in the `predicted` list of dictionaries, append the gold `detected` label to the predicted list as a new key:value as 'gold label: *True* or *False*.

***Note:*** the `gold` data contains only all of the **actual True** values, if there is a False entry in the `predicted` which is not existing in the gold data, then that is considered as a **True Negative**, hence both `gold` & `predicted` have *False* for value. Therefore the gold has less total values than predicted.

```
gold = [{'id': 'ABC', 'detected': True}, 
        {'id':'DEF', 'detected': True}] #contains only all the True values.

predicted = [{'id': 'ABC', 'detected': True}, 
             {'id':'DEF', 'detected': False}, 
             {'id':'GHI', 'detected': True}, 
             {'id':'JKL', 'detected': False}]


for p in predicted:
    if gold in predicted:
        p['gold label'] = True
    else:
        p['gold label'] = False

print(predicted)
```

**current output:**

```
[{'id': 'ABC', 'detected': True, 'gold label': False}, #not correct
 {'id': 'DEF', 'detected': False, 'gold label': False}, #not correct
 {'id': 'GHI', 'detected': True, 'gold label': False},#correct
 {'id': 'JKL', 'detected': False, 'gold label': False}] #correct
```

**desired output:**

```
[{'id': 'ABC', 'detected': True, 'gold label': True}, #correct, match
 {'id': 'DEF', 'detected': False, 'gold label': True}, #correct, mismatch
 {'id': 'GHI', 'detected': True, 'gold label': False}, #correct, mismatch
 {'id': 'JKL', 'detected': False, 'gold label': False}] #correct, match
```

As you can see, I was only able to check if the gold dictionary exists in the predicted list of dictionaries, which would represent a "True" added value. But then it does not consider other options, such as false positives. Any hints so that I can proceed? Should I iterate on both list of dictionaries with nested loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can first generate a dictionary of the gold id:detected pairs, then iterate:

```
gold_ids = {d['id']: d['detected'] for d in gold}
# {'ABC': True, 'DEF': True}

for p in predicted:
    p['gold_label'] = gold_ids.get(p['id'], False)
```

output:

```
[{'id': 'ABC', 'detected': True, 'gold_label': True},
 {'id': 'DEF', 'detected': False, 'gold_label': True},
 {'id': 'GHI', 'detected': True, 'gold_label': False},
 {'id': 'JKL', 'detected': False, 'gold_label': False}]
```

Comment: Op is asking for `p['gold_label'] = p['id'] in gold_ids`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right I thought gold could contain `False`, but this should give the same result no? just more generic in case gold could contain a `False`

Comment: OP provides no such insight, just an attempted reference implementation